# How many paths are there from one vertex of a subdivided triangle to another?

Tags: combinations

Other than counting, is there any shortcut to solve this?

Using only the paths and the indicated directions, how many
different routes are there from $A$ to $J$?

My answer is $22$.

[image]

Comment: Let me suggest that you improve this problem (and eliminate exhaustive solutions) by generalizing to equilateral triangles of arbitrary number, $k$, of levels.

Comment: This sum is $\, _2F_1(-n,n+1;2;-1)$, where $F$ is the HyperGeometric function.  Here's a table:  $$\{ \{0, 1\}, \{1, 2\} , \{2, 6 \} , \{3, 22 \}, \{ 4, 90 \}, \{5 , 394 \}, \{6, 1806 \}, \{7, 8558 \}, \{8, 41586 \} \}$$

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: Can you refer me to something that connects the difference equation to the HyperGeometric function please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building upon a prior comment answer, we have:

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^n C_k {n+k \choose 2k} = \, _2F_1(-n,n+1;2;-1)$$

where $C_n$ is the $n$th Catalan number and $F$ is the [HyperGeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).

Here's a table:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 2 \\
 2 & 6 \\
 3 & 22 \\
 4 & 90 \\
 5 & 394 \\
 6 & 1806 \\
 7 & 8558 \\
 8 & 41586 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 5):

Put a number on every node, starting with a $1$ on point $A$. The numbers you put on node is how many ways to get to this particular node. It is the sum of every nodes that lead to it.

```
        1
      2   1
    6   4   1
 22  16   6   1
```

You are right, there are $22$ ways to get from $A$ to $J$.

Comment: Isn't this "counting"—the method the OP explicitly excluded?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I considered counting to be exhaustive, i.e. finding the exact $22$ ways. But if it is OP's ways, I'll delete my answer.

Comment: I'll leave that up to the OP.  Moreover, it seems that @bof has a functional solution.

Answer (score 4):

The numbers given by @David G. Stork in comments and answers are the Schröder numbers $S_n$

Quoting the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der_number) they

"*describe the number of lattice paths from the southwest corner $(0,0)$ of an $(n \times n)$ grid to the northeast corner $(n,n)$ using only single steps north, $(0,1)$; northeast, $(1,1)$ or east, $(1,0)$ that do not rise above the $\text{SW-NE}$ diagonal."*

You could find them in sequence $A006318$ in $OEIS$.

Comment: Thanks... didn't know that!  (+1).